# Source code does not match the bytecode. Decompiled .class file bytecode version 51.0 (Java 7)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to execute sendEmailVerification method of the Firebase I observe this error message while debugging: "Source code does not match the bytecode" [image] It also says: "Decompiled .class file bytecode version 51.0 (Java 7).

By the way I am not having any trouble with older projects using same sendEmailVerification code. But in this new projects I don't know why this is happening.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xblae.png]

gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zop.mylastapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

}
```

gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: your older project must having older version of firebase dependencies and did you try "Invalidate Caches / Restart ..."?

Comment: I have tried it now but it hasn't work. I also deleted "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.firebase" then "invalidate caches/restart" but it didn't work either.

My older projects also have same dependencies.

Comment: Older project having same dependency versions?